# drupal POST Content-Length exceeds the limit

Tags: drupal, file-upload

hi i got list of warning regarding file size when i try to upload an image using file upload.

```
"POST Content-Length of 12223490 bytes exceeds the limit of 8388608 bytes in Unknown on line 0"
```

My question is how to avoid displaying warning messages (i got 5 warnings). I dont want to increase the file size limit just handle it with showing single warning msg to user rather than a list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can avoid displaying the warnings by settings the `display_errors` setting to false. Just make sure you log the errors so you can troubleshoot problems later.

Comment: ya understood but these warnings completely collapses the page.(i mean display)

Answer (score 2):

Check at php.ini:

post_max_size and upload_max_filesize